# How to pull a chain using jQuery draggable event without effecting the pendulum movement

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am developing a website with some animation on it.I am doing this using `jQuery animate` function.There is a image of flush toilet and if someone drag/pull the chain it should be flushed. Please refer below image

[image: Not pulled]

Chain is continously moving which working fine by using [jQuery Pendulum](http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/jquery-pendulum-animation-pivot-point/). Now what I did is if someone click on the chain it will flushed out as below :-

[image: Pulled]

The code which I'm using is :-

```
var rotation = 3;
            var swingtime = 1603;

            function init() {
                $('#pendulum-parent').animate({rotate: rotation}, 0, function () {
                    $('#pendulum-parent').css("display", "block");
                    rotation *= -1;
                    pendulumswing();
                });
            }

            function pendulumswing() {
                $('#pendulum-parent').animate({rotate: rotation},swingtime, "swing", function(){
                     rotation *= -1;
                     pendulumswing();
                });
            }

            init();


            $('.pull_chain').on("click",function()
            {

                $('.flush_handle').addClass('flush_handle1');
                $('#pendulum-child').addClass('pull_chain1');

            });

            setInterval(function(){$('.flush_handle').removeClass('flush_handle1')}, 6000);
            setInterval(function(){$('#pendulum-child').removeClass('pull_chain1')}, 6000);
```

HTML Code :-

```
<div class="flush_handle"><img src="images/flush-handle.png" /></div>
    <div class="flush_chain">
        <div id="pendulum-parent">
            <div id="pendulum-child"><a class="pull_chain" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div> <!-- Chain image -- >
        </div>
    </div>
```

There is no problem in the above code it is successfully executed but I want the same effect when someone pull/drag the chain. I am doing this for first time and need your help.

**The handle is a different image and chain is a different image. Also the chain moving like a pendulum continously.** Sorry for my bad English and any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution, I have remove the click functionality and use the follwing code :-

```
$('#pendulum-child').draggable(
                {  
                    start: function(event, ui) {
                        $('.flush_handle').addClass('flush_handle1');
                    },
                    axis: 'y',
                    revert: function( event, ui ) {

                        $('.flush_handle').removeClass('flush_handle1');

                        $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                            top : '3px',
                            left : '-74px'
                        };

                        init()
                        return true;


                    }
                }

            );
```

**CSS :-**

```
#pendulum-child 
{
    width:118px;
    height:255px;
    background-image:url(images/flush-chain.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    left:-74px;
    top:3px;
}
#pendulum-parent 
{
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
}
```